# Is there a way to add event action on readonly textfield in pdf by javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, readonly

I have a form with one Radio Button group (let's say Yes or No) and one text field. By default/at opening the pdf, the textfield is readonly. One can type anything to the textfield, must have to check either Yes or No radio button. If no radio button is checked and an user goes to type directly on the textfield, a app.alert will be showed up mentioning that "You must have to select either Yes or No radio button to activate this text field".

So, this is the pdf layout:

```
Yes:[radio1] No:[radio1]
Enter your name here:[text1]
```

I have added this document level javascript function for this purpose:

```
function chkRadio(radioName, pointName){
var v = this.getField(radioName).value;
if(v == "Off"){
app.alert("You must have to select either "+pointName+" to activate this field");
}
}
```

and on text1 textfield action tab, I have added following Javascript action on "Mouseup" event:

```
chkRadio("radio1","Yes or No");
```

The above codes works well if the textfield (text1) is not readonly. It can show the app.alert box as usual. But if I set the readonly property of the text field, no event listener is fired. I have tested "Mouse Up", "Mouse Down", "Mouse Enter", "Mouse Exit", "On Focus", "On Blur" event listeners but nothing works! There is no more event listener actions in pdf text field.

So how can I set up that action on a readonly field itself?

Comment: In Acrobat, readonly fields cannot be interacted with. What you want to do instead is make the text field hidden until yes or no is selected and then show it.

Comment: @joelgeraci, good suggestion! I will actively think about it. Thanks